# (603 · 6004 + 60005) mod 6 is equal to?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Any help here? i have an upcoming exam, and the question in some of the exercises that im practicing on are (603 · 6004 + 60005) mod 6 is equal

I just dont understand how to do it.
The way i saw it was to do
[603 (MOD 6) ] * [6004 (MOD 6) ]
There by
using the formular
n= qm + R
603 = 100*6 + 3
6004 = 1000*6+ 4
Then using these number 
3*4  (MOD 6)
12 (MOD 6)
12 = 1*6 + 6
12 = 6 MOD 6
But the solutions says 5 ? I dont get it?

Comment: you've 60005 mod 6 = 5

Answer (score 2):

${\rm mod}\ 6\!:\,\ 6x\!+\!\color{#c00}y\equiv \color{#c00}y,\ $ so $\ (6i\!+\!\color{#c00}a)(6j\!+\!\color{#c00}b)+6k\!+\!\color{#c00}c \,\equiv\,  \color{#c00}{ab}+\color{#c00}c\ $ by [Basic Congruence Rules.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

Answer (score 1):

$603=600+3 \equiv 0 +3 \equiv 3$ mod 6. $6004=6000+4 \equiv 0+4$ mod 6. $60005=60000+5 \equiv 0 +5 $ mod 6. Hence, $603 \times 6004+60005 \equiv 3 \times 4+5 \equiv 12+5 \equiv 5$ mod 6

Comment: So my mistake was that i forgot to do the same with 60005? But was everything besides that correct?

Comment: yes @ABCCode...

Comment: There is another exercise which says exactly the same but with mod 10 
(603 · 6004 + 60005) mod 10 is equal to? 
I did everything just as before and got the same 3 x 4 + 5 however it says the result is 7 in this case?

Comment: Then the result is $10 \times 5 \equiv 20 \equiv  18+2 \equiv 2$ mod 6

Comment: I still dont get it 10 x 5 why are you doing that? Im new to the topic and also understanding ≡ so if you break it into pieces it would be a lot easier to understand

Comment: $ab$ mod 6 is the same as $a$ mod $6 \times b$ mod $6$. Now, in our case, we've proven that $(603 \times 604 +60005) \equiv 5$ mod 6, so $10(603 \times 6004+60005)$ mod $6$ is $10$ mod $6 \times 5$ mod $6$ and hence is $4 \times 5$ mod 6, $20$ mod 6 hence 2,

Comment: Are you sure that you got the questions?

(603 · 6004 + 60005) mod 10

I just can't seem to grasp it?

Comment: Because i wrote mod 10 (603 · 6004 + 60005) mod 10 so maybe you misunderstood

Comment: Ohhh! $603 \times 6004+60005 \equiv 10\times 60 +3 + 10 \times 600 +4+10 \times 6000 +5 \equiv 3+4+5 \equiv 12 \equiv 2$ mod $10$.